# Cant override UIButton titleLabel properties from button outlet programmatically

Tags: ios, swift3, uibutton, storyboard

So i am using size classes in my storyboard. The button is in my storyboard is using autolayout and its fine and all.

I made an outlet to my ViewController and i am trying to change the title label text and text color, neither of which are working. However, the corner radius and background color are working.

```
  @IBOutlet weak var cancelButton_iPhone: UIButton!

  func setupButtons() {
    cancelButton_iPhone.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
    cancelButton_iPhone.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1, green:1, blue:1, alpha:0.15)
    cancelButton_iPhone.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    cancelButton_iPhone.titleLabel?.text = "testtest"
  }
```

setupButtons() is being called in ViewWillAppear. Ive tried ViewDidLoad as well and no difference.

In the storyboard, the cancelButton_iPhone text is set to "Cancel" and the textcolor is set to Yellow. And this is what is being reflected in my app.  Instead of the "testtest" and white text.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property return title views,will always create them if necessary,and always returns nil for system buttons.And UIButton is subclass of UIControl,so you always need to specify ControlState when updating button's title! You can call the func    `setTitle(_ title: String?, for state: UIControlState)` to set button's title,so does button's titleColor.

Answer (score 0):

For button titles you should use these methods.
func setTitleColor(_ color: UIColor?, for state: UIControlState)
func setTitle(_ title: String?, for state: UIControlState)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var cancelButton_iPhone: UIButton!

func setupButtons() {
    cancelButton_iPhone.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
    cancelButton_iPhone.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1, green:1, blue:1, alpha:0.15)
    cancelButton_iPhone.setTitle("testtest", for: .normal)
    cancelButton_iPhone.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
}
```

Hope it helps.